# How to separate each word in a file and display each word and number of each word in the table?

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I don't know anything about that. May you explain with detail to me, please?

Comment: Please first post your efforts. Show us what have you done. [See this](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I just looking for a suitable code, but I can't found it. Could you help me, please?

Comment: please make some efforts, just try to do something. Have you tried to read the file?

Comment: yes, I have. Ok, I will try. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

- Load the contents of the file into a string
- Call the split operation `string.split(" ")` and assign the result to an array object
- Create a `HashMap` to store your results
- Use a for loop to iterate over the array

  - If the value is already in the map `map.contains("example")` then update the value to increment the occurrence
  - Otherwise add the new value to the map `map.put("example", 1)`

There are many tutorials dealing with the steps outlined above and you should be able to track them down rather easily.

Comment: I will try again. But it's not easy for me. Please help.

Comment: Which step are you getting stuck at?
The first one looks something like this.
InputStream f = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\temp\test.txt"));
String string = f.read();